# filp/Whoops package still show old UI after upgrading to Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

With the release of Laravel 5.5 last week, the package `filp/Whoops` got revamped.

However, if you follow the official [Laravel 5.5 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade), it does not mention anything about `filp/Whoops`.

As a result, you will still have the old `filp/Whoops` UI. So how do you get the new `filp/Whoops` version with Laravel 5.5?

**OLD UI in Laravel 5.4:**

[image]

**New UI in Laravel 5.5:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that you simply need to add it manually to your composer.json. This is undocumented in the official upgrade guide at the time of writing.

```
composer require filp/whoops
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you should look at `https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json` and make sure you have all the dependencies mentioned there in correct versions.

Probably when you are making such migration (from Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 5.5) you should also remove `composer.lock` file and `vendor` directory and run `composer install` to install latest versions of packages.